# Should i be able to step through WCF code if the service is running on a remote machine?

Tags: wcf

Should i be able to step through WCF code if the service is running on a remote machine?

If not is there a debugger setting that will let me do this? I have the code loaded in the solution I am calling it from, but when I step through it doesn't step into the WCF code.

The method I'm calling is not oneway either should that matter.

I have VS2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use remote debugging if its not hosted on IIS.

If it is hosted on a remote IIS though [here](http://cedricboudoya.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!7F839BFE7AB33F87!321.entry) are instructions for how you can debug it.

Comment: That link is broken but I would very much like to read it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the Remote Debugger on the remote machine, and attach to the remote process (in Visual Studio, Debug/Attach/..other machine.../process of your service.
If you have breakpoints set, they will get hit in the process running remotely.

How to set up remote debugging:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the remote debugging tutorials people have mentioned, the "Step Into" feature does not cross process boundaries.  You'll have to set a breakpoint in the service code to get it to stop on the other side.

It might be obvious, but to some people it is not.